# How to add fixed text to left of AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I want to implement AutoCompleteTextView something like what Gmail app in Android does.
I am not sure how to set "To" fixed text on the left side of AutoCompleteTextView.
How is this implemented? Do I have to put TextView inside AutoCompleteTextView to show "To" label. If I do that my cursor starts from the beginning of AutoCompleteTextView and not after TextView.

How should I achieve this view

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `TextView` to the left of the `AutoCompleteTextView`. Use a horizontal `LinearLayout` for that. You can set the border (the underline with the little ticks) on the linear layout if you want one.

Comment: that's actually probably how it is done. a viewgroup (probably a linear layout) is used to put a TextView next to an autocomplete view, then you have to change the style the the autocomplete to avoid having decoration, and change the style of the viewgroup to look like it is the autocomplete view.

Answer (score 0):

My style of implementation of it is to use [android:drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft). Create a drawable(could be image) first which in your case "To". Then apply it in the xml declaration of your AutoCompleteTextView like this.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/auto_complete_textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/to_drawable_label"/>
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: then localization would become quite complex, not to mention changes in theme, font...

Comment: no need for drawableLeft, just custom background Drawable would do the trick

Comment: A custom background is still going to look very strange if someone changes the default font size.

Comment: How to set custom background drawable?

Answer (score -1):

you just need to create an adapter and set it to AutocomleteTextView.